# Cannot index file larger than 100MB in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, bulkinsert

I am trying to index a json file size of 128MB.But due to some reason, I am not able to index it and it shows no error , nothing. But if I break the file to two files size 50mb and 60mb or any size less than 100mb, the file is indexed. Since it gives me no error, I have no idea why I cannot index the file

I am using this command

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/novcart/sales/_bulk' --data-binary @novcart2.json
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default ES is configured to handle payloads of 100MB maximum. The setting you need to change is called [`http.max_content_length`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html#_settings_2).

You can increase this limit simply by adding this to your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file and restarting ES:

```
http.max_content_length: 150mb
```